# Ubuntu 13.04 : Logout button has gone missing

Tags: 13.04, desktop-environments, window

Somehow my logout/poweroff button has gone missing from the desktop, how do I restore it?

Also I used to be able to select the WM to use before logging in (e.g. Unity, Gnome etc), but I don't get that option anymore, how do I restore that?

My update log is at http://pastebin.com/wCWBW7iu

Comment: Have you done **something** before the problem appeared?? Please give more details about the issue.

Comment: Nothing that should have caused the problem.  An apt-get update at most.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the contents of `/var/log/apt/history.log`.